# How do get the view that is the tapped detail-disclosure-button

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

The cell in this iPhone TableView definitely has a Detail-Disclosure-Button.

When I tap it... shouldn't this code give me access to the button?

Instead detailButton is always just null.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *detailButton = (UIButton *)[aCell accessoryView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you over-riding the cell accessory button in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

`accessoryView` is provided for your own customization, to override `accessoryType`.  The table view cell will internally handle whatever you assign to `accessoryType` without affecting `accessoryView`.